# Why is the site so set on putting down new users?

Tags: discussion, comments, search, down-votes, new-users

## Disclaimer:

If I mention any users in this post, I am not attacking them personally. I do not know them and think that they are good people.

---

I am slightly new to this site, *why is it that so many veteran users are set on putting down questions from new users?*

Within the first five minutes of me asking a question(and this might be someone else's experience), mods and veteran users immediately downvote and mark it as a duplicate, and then link to a question asked 10 years ago.

**I was not here 10 years ago** and plus, when I search my question topic before posting, I can never find the questions that they link in the search menu.

---

[image: Picture of downputting comments]
A user got mad at *me* for deleting and then reposting a comment because I forgot to tag him. He said that his prior comment was to "prompt you to add more information to your post", even though he never said that explicitly and did not mark the question as 'unclear'. That's not helpful at all.

### ---

Maybe this discussion question will get downvoted as well, but I feel as if there is no room for people as a whole to express questions pertaining to their experiences. Questions that are 'copied' and called 'duplicates' are just a user asking their question from their perspective. Some people don't want an answer to somebody else's question.

But I can't give problems without answers. I propose a restructure of the searching algorithm, so that users searching for an old question can find it easier. I also propose that we put something in the Code of Conduct especially pertaining to New Contributors, because the tag doesn't seem to change anybody's mind about how to respond to their questions and answers.

Comment: 1. You need to use other filters or sorting to find those in the side bar. 2. You can always edit, ping and explain why it is not a duplicate. 3.  How do you expect people to return back to your Q to mark it duplicate when you are old enough for the site. You needed answers quickly, they are given quickly. 4. now for pinging, I think I am about to ask a Q about that here as well

Comment: It doesn't seem [from the timeline](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/174832/timeline) that your question has received any downvotes, nor has it ever been close as a duplicate so I'm rather confused.

Comment: @RobertLongson, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637823/java-scanner-if-statement-issue

Comment: Which issue did you want to discuss here? You seem to have 2 questions with different things you want to discuss. If it's the question on Stack Overflow I'd recommend asking on [its meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: For the record, @WeaponGod243, I'm not mad at you, and I sincerely apologize for making you feel that way. I just wanted to explain that individual replies to each comment isn't the norm for this site - so if I or another user doesn't reply, that doesn't mean they didn't see your message. The reason I didn't mark your question as unclear is that, since I'm a mod, that would have closed the question instantly, and I thought that would give you an unnecessarily negative experience. I figured a comment showing what areas a reader might be uncertain about would be enough to prompt you to add info.

Comment: @DMGregory But if there are multiple people commenting in a thread, it is best to ping people. So I feel it is a good habit to always do that. Just like in this thread.

Comment: I have no argument against tagging where appropriate, @ankiiiiiii. In this particular instance, I'd already been pinged by the system two days before, saw there was nothing that demanded my attention (at least some new information had been added to the thread, which was what I'd hoped for -  maybe someone can now write a better answer with the extra info), and moved on. So deleting and re-posting the same comment two days later didn't materially improve the situation. I certainly could have been more clear in how I stated that though!

Comment: Sure, but it you delete and repost, the user gets *two* notifications no?

Comment: yeah maybe OP didn't know about this special case of notification without @ in case of a single participant. Also, I didn't see the timeline of the comments. I thought it happened quickly. Still slightly bad.

Comment: Let's flip this around; why are new users so intent on assuming hostility and negativity when they don't know how the site works?  Give respect, get respect.

Answer (score 23):

> why is it that so many veteran users are set on putting down questions from new users?

Let me counter that with a question for you to answer: Why do so many new users assume bad faith of veteran users?

> Within the first five minutes of me asking a question(and this might be someone else's experience), mods and veteran users immediately downvote and mark it as a duplicate, and then link to a question asked 10 years ago.

Yes, isn't that awesome? Within 5 minutes you've been guided to an answer that has been carefully curated over the last 6 to 8 years to be given to you once your question popped up.

> I was not here 10 years ago and plus, when I search my question topic before posting, I can never find the questions that they link in the search menu.

I give you that the on-site search is sub-par. It works when you know exactly what you're looking for but if you misspelled or use a slightly under used synonym search will return you nothing. Better rely on Google/Bing/DuckDuckGo to do the first shake down of potential articles to research. It also helps if you include typical search terms you used in your question. An experienced pair of eyes will notice why you didn't find things that solved your issue. And with your search terms your question might now serve as a signpost to the correct answer. That is still beneficial.

> A user got mad at me for deleting and then reposting a comment because I forgot to tag him. He said that his prior comment was to "prompt you to add more information to your post", even though he never said that explicitly and did not mark the question as 'unclear'. That's not helpful at all.

I don't see anyone being mad there, just to the point. That might not be a communication style that works best for you but you have to be really unlucky to find that single user that appears to be rude/aggressive by default. Despite popular belief, the overwhelmingly majority of users that take care by leaving a comment and pointing out solutions to raised questions, mean to be friendly and helpful. It hurts them as much as it hurts you if that doesn't pan out.

> Maybe this discussion question will get downvoted as well, but I feel as if there is no room for people as a whole to express questions pertaining to their experiences. Questions that are 'copied' and called 'duplicates' are just a user asking their question from their perspective. Some people don't want an answer to somebody else's question.

That sounds all very charitable but here I have to politely point out that on the SE network we're not optimizing to just help you and only you. The network tries to build a canonical collection of knowledge based on questions and their answers. That does mean that the posts have to be self-contained and self-supporting for visitors to come. For that reason posts get curated more then on an regular forum. If you honestly don't care about the next wave of new users struggling with similar issues and don't want to put that little bit more effort in then maybe reddit or Quora are a better venue.

> But I can't give problems without answers. I propose a restructure of the searching algorithm, so that users searching for an old question can find it easier.

Totally agree. You might want to [support some of the open feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsearch%5D+%5Bfeature-request%5D+closed%3Ano+-%5Bstatus-*%5D)  on that topic.

> I also propose that we put something in the Code of Conduct especially pertaining to New Contributors, because the tag doesn't seem to change anybody's mind about how to respond to their questions and answers.

If we agree on the fact that we're all here in our free time, participate with an open mind and all parties assume good faith, I don't think we need anything special in the code of conduct, after all [*Edits, comments, and suggestions are healthy parts of our community.*](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Answer (score 13):

The thing to focus on is not that the other question is 10 years old, but do the answers to that question solve my problem.

If they do then great, you've got what you came for. If not edit your question to explain why so we can get it reopened and try again.

Try to remember we're here to help and also we're here to try to create a library of great questions and their answers so sometimes we may try to encourage you to help yourself by editing your question into a form that's more likely to be answered.

Think of a downvote as a prompt to do better, go back and ask yourself or ask a friend if you can whether there's anything unclear about your question. Have you assumed anything that you need to make explicit?

And try to think the best of people, that they are trying to help. We don't really want to close questions as unclear if we can instead get you to make them clear.

Answer (score 6):

They're trying to guide you in their own way. You don't *necessarily* need to tag folks - the *proper* usage of comments is as a transient way to get a better question or answer.

We totally can do better there - but often the *right* thing to do when prompted for more information is to edit. There's a bit of a tactical advantage in making your (or the first) edit a great one since it throws it back into the reopen queue.

We also typically treat things "in commons". You rarely need to ping a specific user - and in many cases folks get notified for replies anyway.

> Within the first five minutes of me asking a question(and this might be someone else's experience), mods and veteran users immediately downvote and mark it as a duplicate, and then link to a question asked 10 years ago.

Funny thing is I've probably had that happen before. That said, while SE's search is pretty terrible (and the easiest  way to find a question is typing a title), we're also often pretty high up on google searches.

Sometimes I suspect the "secret" of using the network is to look for answers, not just ask questions.

For your closed question - *does the dupe target solve your problem?*. If not, edit your question to reflect how it dosen't - it'll get thrown back into the reopening queue. If it does - well, you got what you were looking for.

Comment: I'd recommend also adding that a close-as-duplicate vote isn't necessarily a judgement against the question or the person asking it. [Having duplicate questions can actually improve the search "catchment area" of a topic](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), so it's often useful to think "Cool, you provided a new entry point to lead users to this existing info" rather than "You're bad for not finding this info in the first place" ;)